# Loop through Excel files in subfolders and copy and paste data to one sheet

Tags: vba

I'm trying to loop through all Excel files in subfolders of a folder designated by a user and copy and paste data to a new workbook named "Compilation". This code works up to creating and saving a new workbook but data wouldn't copy and paste to the workbook.

Can anyone please help?

```
Sub LoopCopyPasteSubfolders()

Dim fso As Object
Dim wb As Object
Dim folder As Object
Dim subfolder As Object
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim FdrPicker As FileDialog

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Set FdrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FdrPicker
    .Title = "Select a Target Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        MyPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

NextCode:
'in case of cancel
If MyPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings Else

Dim NewWB As Workbook
Set NewWB = Workbooks.Add

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Batch\Compilation.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.getfolder(MyPath)
Set subfolder = folder.subfolders
For Each subfolder In folder.subfolders
Set wb = subfolder.Files

 For Each wb In subfolder.Files
    If fso.GetExtensionName(wb.Path) = "*.xls*" Then
    Workbooks.Open wb, ReadOnly:=True
    Range("A1:M1").End(xlDown).Copy
    For Each cell In Workbooks("Compilation").Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Cells   
        If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then cell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        'exit when value pasted to the first empty row

        Exit For
    Next cell
End If

Next wb

Next subfolder  

'reset settings to default    
ResetSettings:

Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
Application.EnableEvents = True    
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is finalized code that loops through all subfolders in a folder selected by user and copy and paste data in any Excel files in subfolders to a new workbook.

```
Sub LoopCopyPasteSubfoldersIII()

Dim fso As Object
Dim wb As Object
Dim folder As Object
Dim subfolder As Object
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim FdrPicker As FileDialog
Dim wba As Workbook
Dim wbn As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Set FdrPicker = 
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FdrPicker
.Title = "Select a Target Folder"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    MyPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

NextCode:
'in case of cancel
MyPath = MyPath
If MyPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings Else

Dim NewWB As Workbook
Set NewWB = Workbooks.Add

NewWB.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\405458\Downloads\Compilation.xlsx", 
FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.getfolder(MyPath)

For Each subfolder In folder.subfolders

For Each wb In subfolder.Files
    If fso.GetExtensionName(wb.Path) = "xlsx" Then
        wbn = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(wb)
        Set wba = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=wbn)

   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:M1").Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy
            For Each cell In Workbooks("Compilation").Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Cells
                If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then
                   cell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                'exit when value pasted to the first empty row
                Exit For
                Else
                End If
            Next cell
        wba.Close False
        NewWB.Save
    End If
Next wb

Next subfolder

'reset settings to default
ResetSettings:

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub LoopCopyPasteSubfoldersIII()

Dim fso As Object
Dim wb As Object
Dim folder As Object
Dim subfolder As Object
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim FdrPicker As FileDialog
Dim wba As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Set FdrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FdrPicker
.Title = "Select a Target Folder"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    MyPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

NextCode:
'in case of cancel
MyPath = MyPath
If MyPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings Else

Dim NewWB As Workbook
Set NewWB = Workbooks.Add

NewWB.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\405458\Downloads\Compilation.xlsx", 
FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.getfolder(MyPath)

For Each subfolder In folder.subfolders

For Each wb In subfolder.Files
    If fso.GetExtensionName(wb.Path) = "*.xls*" Then
        Set wba = Workbooks.Open(wb.Path & "\" & wb.FullName, , True)
            wba.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:M20").Copy
            For Each cell In 
Workbooks("Compilation").Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Cells
                If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then
                   cell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                'exit when value pasted to the first empty row
                End If
            Exit For

            Next cell
        wba.Close False
        NewWB.Save
    End If
Next wb

Next subfolder

'reset settings to default
ResetSettings:

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I got "Compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" message so I deleted True after NewWB.Save. The error message went away but the code still won't copy & paste data..

Comment: Try debugging using F8 ... See if data is being pasted or not after each step. Also I have made few more changes  in the answer .. Try this now.

Comment: Thanks Mikku, when the run is at "Set wba = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=wb.FullName)" error message "Object doesn't support this property or method" shows up. It seems to be a problem with referencing the file directory.

Comment: @BonnieJ   ..... That line is `Set wba = Workbooks.Open(wb.Path & "\" & wb.FullName, , True)` .... Check again using the same F8 and changing this line.

Comment: If you will use `Set wba = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=wb.FullName)` , Then you are only passing the name of the file, not the path!

Comment: I get the same error message with that part replaced. It looks FullName property includes both path and file name. Check this out https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/path-fullname.html

Comment: I solved the problem! I replaced  If fso.GetExtensionName(wb.Path) = "*.xls*" Then
        Set wba = Workbooks.Open(wb.Path & "\" & wb.FullName, , True)            with            If fso.GetExtensionName(wb.Path) = "xlsx" Then
            wbn = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(wb)
            Set wba = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=wbn)     '''First issue was GetExtensionName method should have exact extension name(wildcard * doesn't work for this method). Second issue was referencing wb file with .FullName doesn't work as wb is defined as object. GetAbsolutePathName method solves the problem.

Comment: I will organize and load final code in the next few days - got caught up with work today. Thanks!!